# How to combine 2 variables and ignore NAs

Tags: r

I have some data like these

```
var1   var2
10     NA
101    NA
NA     86
11     NA
NA     11
NA     61
```

If one variable is NA then the other one is not, and vice-versa.

How can I combine them into a single variable:

```
var3
10
101
86
11
11
61
```

I can do it easily with a loop, but it is quite slow, so I would like to find an easier way. I thought about assigning 0 to the values that are NA and then just adding the variables together...is there a better way ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Various methods exist. Here's one way:

```
var3 <- ifelse(!is.na(var1),var1,var2)
```

Here it is working on your example:

```
  var1 <- c(10,101,NA,11,NA,NA)
  var2 <- c(NA,NA,86,NA,11,61)

  var3 <- ifelse(!is.na(var1),var1,var2)

 > var3
 [1]  10 101  86  11  11  61
```

This method is relatively general - it works with non-numeric data for example:

```
  var1 <- c("AB","WZ",NA,"MN",NA,NA)
  var2 <- c(NA,NA,"QT",NA,"MN","RS")

  var3 <- ifelse(!is.na(var1),var1,var2)

 > var3
 [1] "AB" "WZ" "QT" "MN" "MN" "RS"
```

The suggestion of replacing `NA` with `0` and adding wouldn't work in that case.

Comment: woops, my mistake.  I missed OP's statement that only one will be NA at a time.

Answer (score 5):

`rowSums` with `na.rm = TRUE` will do this. (This is your suggested solution really...)

Assuming your data are in a `data.frame` `DF` and your comment

> If one variable is NA then the other one is not, and vice-versa.

is true.

```
 DF$var3 <- rowSums(DF[, c('var1','var2')], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: I think this is one of the best of the offered solutions.  However, you'll have to watch for rows where both `x` and `y` contain data!

Comment: True, although the question did state that this wasn't possible.

Comment: yup! but in my experience hard and fast rules like that seem to be only made to be broken!

Comment: if (!all(is.na(rowSums(x)))) stop("More than one value is present")